Why does the Chip8 subtraction opcode involve a bitmask AND a bitshift?
I'm following the Chip8 guide written by Austin Morlan: https://austinmorlan.com/posts/chip8_emulator/
In his description of the opcode for SUB, he has this code:
void Chip8::OP_8xy5()
{
    uint8_t Vx = (opcode & 0x0F00u) >> 8u;
    uint8_t Vy = (opcode & 0x00F0u) >> 4u;

    if (registers[Vx] > registers[Vy])
    {
        registers[0xF] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        registers[0xF] = 0;
    }

    registers[Vx] -= registers[Vy];
}

I have 2 questions about how this works:

Why do we mask the opcode with 0x0F00u in one case and with 0x00F0u in the other?

uint8_t Vx = (opcode & 0x0F00u) >> 8u;
uint8_t Vy = (opcode & 0x00F0u) >> 4u;


Why do we shift Vx by 8 bits and Vy by 4?

Please help me understand how this works. This is not for any kind of assignment. I'm a web developer by day and currently exploring Emulator Development.

The first one has 8 low bits that are 0; the second one has 4. The shift moves the significant bits down to the low end.

@PeteBecker sorry I don't follow. Could you elaborate more? If it makes sense I will mark your answer as correct.

The CHIP-8 implementation has 16 registers, implemented as a 16-element array. Thus, any register can be addressed by a 4-bit field (a nibble) in the opcode.
In the SUB instruction the registers holding the operands are indicated by the values in nibbles 1 and 2, where nibble 0 is the least significant nibble.
By masking with 0x0f00 and shifting right by 8 bits the register indicated by nibble 2 is moved to nibble 0 where it can be used as an offset into the register array.
Similarly, masking by 0x00f0 and shifting right four bits extracts the offset
for the second operand in the register array.
For example
SUB Vx, Vy where Vx = 3 and Vy = 5 has this bit pattern:

    0100 0011 1001 1001
      8   Vx   Vy   3

(The values 8 and 3 are part of the opcode that identified this as a SUB instruction)

Masking with 0x0f00 (for Vx) gives 

    0000 0011 0000 0000
          Vx

Shifting right 8 bits gives

    0000 0000 0000 0011
                    Vx


(The C variable Vx is actually an unsigned 8-bit int, so the C compiler coerces the result to 0000 0011, but we can ignore that for now.)
This give a value of 3 that can be used as an offset into the registers array to identify the value for this operand.
The process is similar for the other operand

Sorry I still don't fully follow. Could you include an example that shows how the nibbles shift?

I don't see how it could be any clearer.  The constant is in the low order 4 bits of the opcode.  The Vy value is in the next 4 bits.  The Vx value is in the next 4 bits.  So, to extract Vy, it has to be shifted right by 4 bits.  Otherwise, 1001_0000 is the value 144 instead of 1001 the value 9.  Shifting and masking is ubiquitous in CPU coding.
